# Check if word from one input exist in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little problem, when I want to check if a word from one input, exist in another input.

The first input can only contain one word. When I've typed a word and then hit space, the script should check if the word already exist in the second input.
It works fine, except when I'm using a `+`-sign.

If `c++` exist in the second input, and I'm typing `c` in the first input, and then hit space, it tells that the word already exist, which is incorrect.

I've tried to search to web for a solution, and what I've found was something with `regEx` and `escaping`, but it still doesn't seems to work.

**This is what I've tried so far:**

```
$word = $('input.word').val();
$check_here = $('input.check-here').val();

function escapeRegExp(string) {
    $regex = '\\b';
    $regex += string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    $regex += '\\b';
    $result = new RegExp($regex, "g");
    return $result;
}

if ( escapeRegExp( $word ).test( $check_here ) ) {
    alert("Word exist");
}
else {
    alert("Word do not exist");
}
```

[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2tr9tud/)

**PS:** I've also tried to put `$check_here` in the `escapeRegExp()` function, like I've done with `$word`, but that do not work at all.

A friendly person, who please can tell me whats wrong?

Comment: @Gael's answer below is the way you should be doing this. As for why your current code doesn't work - this is because the \b at the end of the regex you create is actually matching the first + in "c++" as a word boundary. This is because a + is not considered a character that normally appears in words - hence it is not a 'word character' and therefore must be a word boundary character. If you really want to use this approach instead of the below, try using (?!\w) instead of \b at the end of your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why you want to escape the string.

Your escapeRegExp function (which does not escapes anymore so now called regExp) should be simple like this:

```
function regExp(string) {
    //this regex will match only if there is the same string in your list. 
    //Only spaces are used as boundaries. 
    return  new RegExp("\s"+string+"\s", "g");
}
```

As an alternative, you can put all the words in the second input in an array, like in my fiddle:

```
    var existingWords = $('input#wordList').val().split(/ /);
    if( existingWords.indexOf( word ) >= 0 )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gael/a2tr9tud/1/

Comment: If I want to delete the word from the input, how do I do it then? :)
I have tried with replace(), but that deletes every instance of that character

Comment: $('input#check-word').HTML("")